# cannot delete items from users cart array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const deleteCart = async (req,res,next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
  
    let cart;
    try {
      cart = await Cart.findOneAndDelete(id).populate("user");
      await cart.user.cart.pull(cart);
      await cart.user.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (!cart) {
      return res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable To Delete" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully Deleted" })
  }
```

so i am working on my ecomerce website and i'm having troubles with deleting items from user's cart the code above is supposed to delete items from the cart schema and also from the user's cart array but it only deletes  from the cart schema and the product is still left in the users cart array

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

In `mongoDB` the `pull()` method is used to remove an item from an array that matches a certain criteria.
You are passing the entire cart object to the `pull()` method, which won't work as it won't match any criteria.

Now assuming that `myId` is the ID you are using in your db-schema you could try this:

```
await cart.user.cart.pull({myId: id});
await cart.user.save();
```

##### EDIT:

Knowing your database schema please try this method for deleting:

```
const deleteCart = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    try {
        // Find the user whose cart contains the item
        const user = await User.findOne({ "cart": id });
        
        // Remove the item from the user's cart array
        user.cart.pull(id);
        await user.save();

        // Delete the item
        const cart = await Cart.findByIdAndDelete(id);

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ message: "Unable To Delete" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "Successfully Deleted" });
}
```

This code first finds the user whose cart array contains the item to be deleted by searching for a user with a cart array that includes the item's `id`.

Then it removes that `item` from the user's cart array using the `pull` method.

After that, it saves the user's updated cart array and deletes the item from the cart collection.

Comment: tried this and it deletes the cart from the cart schema but it does not remove the item from the users cart array

Comment: Try changing that line to `await cart.user.cart.pull({myId: cart._id});` and see if that fixes it. Also change `Cart.findOneAndDelete(id)` to `Cart.findOneAndDelete({myId: id})` to pass the *id* as a filter instead of directly passing it.
If it still won't work there must be something with the user schema. Make sure it has a cart field which is an array of cart items and each cart item has an "myId" field.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pull')

Comment: Is the cart array inside your user-schema? Can you share us your schema?

Comment: yes the cart array is in the user-schema

Comment: const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    cart: {
      type: Array,
      ref: "Cart",
      required: false,
    },

Comment: How about my edit of the `deleteCard` function?

Comment: still not working